# XQuery transform string into a datetime (exist-db)

Tags: datetime, xquery, exist-db

I am using XQuery 3.0 for exist-db, and am trying to make the string $value a dateTime object. This is what I've got, but it's not working:

```
let $value := '"2001-10-18T08:47:00"'

if ($key = 'start_time')
    then 
        element { $key } { xs:dateTime(string(replace($value, '"', ''))) }
```

It's saying: illegal lexical form for date-time-like value ''. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the error you're getting with that code - which is incomplete (lacks `return` and `else` clauses, doesn't define `$key`). But paring those issues away, your code runs fine for me, as follows:

```
let $value := '"2001-10-18T08:47:00"'
return
    xs:dateTime(replace($value, '"', ''))
```

The result:

```
2001-10-18T08:47:00
```

Comment: You're right, the XQuery is fine. I managed to track it down to one iteration which has the $value as an empty string rather than a date. Thanks for your help!